# Is there an equivalent of .style.transform that you can use in stimulus.js?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, transform, stimulusjs

I'm fairly new to coding and trying to recreate a simple animated JavaScript clock (from Javascript30 course) in a Rails app using Stimulus (as these are what I'm most familiar with).

I want to change the transform property of the `.hand` class at regular intervals to replicate a ticking clock in Stimulus where you'd use `.style.transform` in JavaScript. I can't understand how to change a property regularly using `.classList`

This is the working code:

```
<body>
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <style>
    .clock {
      width: 30rem;
      height: 30rem;
      border: 20px solid white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
      padding: 2rem;
      box-shadow:
        0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
        inset 0 0 10px black,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .clock-face {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
    }

    .hand {
      width: 50%;
      height: 6px;
      background: black;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform-origin: 100%;
      **transform: rotate(90deg);**
      transition: all 0.05s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
    }
</style>

<script>
  const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
  const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
  const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

  function setDate() {
    const now = new Date();

    const seconds = now.getSeconds();
    const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
    **secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;**

    const mins = now.getMinutes();
    const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds/60)*6) + 90;
    minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

    const hour = now.getHours();
    const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins/60)*30) + 90;
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
  }

  setInterval(setDate, 1000);

  setDate();

</script>
```

What I cannot figure out is how to recreate

```
minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;
```

With the same CSS as above, this HTML with data controllers, targets and actions:

And this Stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  // static targets = [ "output" ]
  static values = { refreshInterval: Number }
  static targets = [ "hour", "min", "sec" ]

  connect() {
    this.setDate();

    if (this.hasRefreshIntervalValue) {
      this.startRefreshing()
    }
  }

  setSeconds(){
    const now = new Date();

    const seconds = now.getSeconds(); 
    const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360 )+ 90;     
    **console.dir(this.secTarget)**
  }

  setDate() {
    this.setSeconds();
  }

  startRefreshing() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setDate()
    }, this.refreshIntervalValue)
  }

}
```